# Replacing empty string column with null in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

How do I replace empty (non null) column of string datatype with null value?

So say the following query returns non zero recordset:-

```
mytable | where mycol == ""
```

Now these are the rows with mycol containing empty strings. I want to replace these with nulls. Now, from what I have read in the kusto documentation we have datatype specific null literals such as int(null),datetime(null),guid(null) etc. But there is no string(null). The closest to string is guid, but when I use it in the following manner, I get an error:-

```
mytable | where mycol == "" | extend test = translate(mycol,guid(null))
```

The error:-

```
translate(): argument #0 must be string literal
```

So what is the way out then?

Update:-

```
datatable(n:int,s:string)
[
    10,"hello",
    10,"",
    11,"world",
    11,"",
    12,""
]
| summarize myset=make_set(s) by n
```

If you execute this, you can see that empty strings are being considered as part of sets. I don't want this, no such empty strings should be part of my array. But at the same time I don't want to lose value of n, and this is exactly what will happen if I if I use isnotempty function. So in the following example, you can see that the row where n=12 is not returned, there is no need to skip n=12, one could always get an empty array:-

```
datatable(n:int,s:string)
[
    10,"hello",
    10,"",
    11,"world",
    11,"",
    12,""
]
| where isnotempty(s)
| summarize myset=make_set(s) by n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently no support for `null` values for the string datatype: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/null-values

I'm pretty certain that in itself, that shouldn't block you from reaching your end goal, but that goal isn't currently clear.

**[update based on your update:]**

```
datatable(n:int,s:string)
[
    10,"hello",
    10,"",
    11,"world",
    11,"",
    12,""
]
| summarize make_set(todynamic(s)) by n
```

Comment: All I need is not to have empty strings in my data , I would like to replace that with null -- so here is the reason, I am doing 'summarize' down the line and an aggregate function make_set gets invoked on the column which contains such empty strings, so in that case empty string appears as a separate entry, I clearly don't want this. It should just not list these entries at all for make_set:-  [
  "",
  "somestring1",
  "somestring2",
  "somestring3"
]

Comment: to make things clearer - i would suggest you provide a query which represents your intention and (minimal) data set using the datatable operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/datatableoperator. I've provided an example in the update to my answer, which you can use as a baseline for your example/clarification

Comment: thx. updated my question with the detailed example based on datatable

Comment: Thanks!, it's still not perfect in the sense it doesn't retain the original datatype. But I think this is as close as we can get.

Comment: Replacing empty string with null is also useful if you want to "| sort by strcol asc nulls last", it does not detect empty string as null in this case